# execute function from console log stopped working in google chrome

Tags: console, google-chrome-extension, version, local-storage

I am have written a Google Chrome extension.  I have a function in the background page that I use to do database maintenance but I only execute it from the console. Here is the structure:  function maintainDb(maintFlag,selectionCrit).  If I want to know how many entries contain the string "Monday" then I type maintainDb("audit","Monday").  If I want to delete these entries, then I type maintainDb("delete","Monday").  I have a few other similar lookup functions, too.

These are nice and simple and until recently worked fine.  Now, however, these functions sometimes will not start at all from the console.  On these occasions the console also no longer prompts me for variables contained in background.html.

But sometimes they do work and that leads me to believe that recent versions of Chrome allow for this feature to be turned on and off.  In addition to that, tabs that I once opened with a specified height and width are now opening full screen.  All this leads me to believe a version change is responsible for this nonsense.

Can anyone help me to understand what's going on?  I need my background functions, particularly to clean up the localStorage database.  Thanks.

PS, if anyone has a burning desire to see that maintenance function, I could post it here for you.  It's not particularly sophisticated but when it works, it's invaluable for deleted dead wood from the localStorage db.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange.

I actually can call extensions functions from the console, even out from extension's developers mode.

The only thing I can think is about your Chrome version.  I think you are sure it's not a **dev** nor **beta** version you are using.  The stable release today is version 17.